# Migrate code Scala to databricks notebook

Tags: scala, databricks

Working to get this code running using notebooks in databricks(already tested and working with an IDE), can not get this working if I change the structure of the code.

```
import java.io.{BufferedReader, InputStreamReader}
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}

object TestUnit {
  val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd")

  case class Averages (cust: String, Num: String, date: String, credit: Double)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val inputFile = "s3a://tfsdl-ghd-wb/raidnd/Cleartablet.csv"
    val outputFile = "s3a://tfsdl-ghd-wb/raidnd/Incte_19&20.csv"
    val fileSystem = getFileSystem(inputFile)
    val inputData = readCSVFileLines(fileSystem, inputFile, skipHeader = true)
      .toSeq
    val filtinp = inputData.filter(x => x.nonEmpty)
      .map(x => x.split(","))
      .map(x => Revenue(x(6), x(5), x(0), x(8).toDouble))

    // Create output writer
    val writer = new PrintWriter(new File(outputFile)) 
    // Header for output CSV file
    writer.write("Date,customer,number,Credit,Average Credit/SKU\n")
    filtinp.foreach{x =>
      val (com1, avg1) = com1Average(filtermp, x)
      val (com2, avg2) = com2Average(filtermp, x)
    }

    // Write row to output csv file
    writer.write(s"${x.day},${x.customer},${x.number},${x.credit},${avgcredit1},${avgcredit2}\n")
    writer.close() // close the writer`
  }
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: It was already discussed - you're using Spark incorrectly, you should use Spark functionality to do the distributed data processing...